# trying to learn animation in WPF with CompositionTarget.Rendering

Tags: wpf, vb.net, composition

I am trying to figure out how to animate/move elements in WPF with VB.NET. It was suggested to me to try using CompositionTarget.Rendering but I am having difficulty getting started. Below is my code and below that is the error message I am getting. Could someone please tell me where I am going going wrong.

Code:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow

    Dim flake0 As New flake

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        canvas1.DataContext = flake0
        AddHandler CompositionTarget.Rendering, AddressOf compo
    End Sub

    Private Sub compo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        flake0.move()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Error:

```
Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another method that accidentally got "handles CompositionTarget.Rendering" tagged to the end of it.